# Syntax Error in my sql query in nodejs | Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Font-end Code

I have lot of subject for user to select more then the ones I post, just for to have an idea of how the front end form look, so it depend on the subject the user select.

```
        <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="subject" value="english" id="customSwitch1">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">Engish Language</label>
            </div>

            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="subject" value="mathematics" id="customSwitch2">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2">Mathematices</label>
            </div>

            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="subject" value="economics" id="customSwitch3">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch3">Economics</label>
            </div>

            <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="subject" value="geography" id="customSwitch4">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch4">Geography</label>
            </div>
```

The is the function that process the reqest.

exports.examsettings = async (req, res) => {

```
const { subject, years, jambno} = req.body;

subject.forEach (subject => console.log(subject))

data.query("SELECT * FROM question WHERE subject = ?" , [subject], async (error, results) => {

    if(error){
        console.log(error);

    } else {
        return res.render("examsettings", {
           message: "Question Fetched Successfully"
           })
    }
})
```

}

And this is the result I get in my console.log

english

mathematics

economics

geography

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'mathematics', 'economics', 'geography'' at line 1

code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',

errno: 1064,

sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'mathematics', 'economics', 'geography'' at line 1",

sqlState: '42000',

index: 0,

sql: "SELECT * FROM question WHERE subject = 'english', 'mathematics', 'economics', 'geography'"
}

Comment: In SQL, when you want to check for multiple matches (in this case subjects) you cannot do `WHERE subject = ?` but you should use `WHERE subject IN (?)` The difference is checking the database for a single value (eg `subject = geography`) vs multiple values (`subject IN ('english', 'mathematics', 'economics', 'geography')`). Note that the IN clause will also work for a single value too (eg `WHERE subject IN ('english')`)

Comment: Will try that, Thanks.

Comment: Tried that this is the new error. Almost the same but a little changes..... syntax to use near '= 'chemistry', 'accounting', 'commerce', 'englishlit'' at line 1",

Comment: Why is there still an equal sign in your query (the error message says `near '= 'chemistry',`)? Have you tested your code with just a single subject to see if that changes the result?